# Rotation matrix seen as transform matrix between bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Hello I am confused about rotation matrices

I can either rotate a point in one direction directly or rotate its base vector in the opposite direction and then project the point onto the rotated base vectors, right?

Let's say I have vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (Cartesian base) and rotate those vectors so I get $v_1 = (\cos a, \sin a)$ and $v_2 = (-\sin a, \cos a)$

Now the last step is the projection.

$$\begin{align*}
    p.x' &= \mathrm{proj}(p)\,\mathrm{to}\,v_1 = \mathrm{dot}(p,v_1) = p.x \cdot \cos a + p.y \cdot \sin a \\
    p.y' &= \mathrm{proj}(p)\,\mathrm{to}\,v_2 = \mathrm{dot}(p,v_2) = -p.x \cdot \sin a + p.y \cdot \cos a
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand, rotation matrix looks like this:

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos a & -\sin a\\
\sin a & \cos a
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

and multiplying it by point $p$ I get

$$\begin{align*}
p.x' &= p.x \cdot \cos a - p.y \cdot \sin a \\
p.y' &= p.x \cdot \sin a + p.y \cdot \cos a
\end{align*}$$

Which gives me different results...what am I missing??

Thanks for your time guys (girls)!

Comment: Please use Mathjax / LaTeX syntax for typsetting equations.

Comment: You should mutiply by a vector or point $1X2$ not a constant $p,$ which only lengthens a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you need to rotate in the opposite direction. That means that you should replace $a$ with $-a$. The cosine term is the same, the sine term changes sign